# Where is Kechror, Turkey?

Tags: turkey, identify-this, religion

I can't seem to locate the town of Kechror, or village of Chukurayva in which I am interested in visiting. I have found a reference to these in an [article](http://peopleofar.wordpress.com/2013/09/19/tzarakar-ancient-armenian-monastery-found/#more-3849) of an re-discovered acient Armenian chruch.

> The renown ancient Armenian monastery complex ‘Tzarakar’ has been
>   discovered near the village of Chukurayva, 5 kms south-east of the
>   fortified town of Kechror, modern-day Turkey (the old Gabeghiank
>   district, Ayrarat province of Greater Armenia). What remains of it are
>   the interior cut-in-rock structures, the exterior buildings are
>   irretrievably lost.

I have no idea where this is, and neither has google maps.

Comment: In Armenian it's ["Կեչրոր"](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/%D4%BF%D5%A5%D5%B9%D6%80%D5%B8%D6%80).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The village you are looking for is called Çukurayva, while [Keçror](http://www.nisanyanmap.com/?lv=2&y=Ke%C3%A7ror&t=&srt=x&u=1&ua=0) is an old Armenian name for the village Tunçkaya.

Answer (score 4):

I found **Çukurayva** with Google search which gave me [a map](http://goo.gl/maps/IjoXM):

[image]

This looks the same as the aerial view on the article.

But nothing around has a name looking like *Kechror*.

Answer (score 3):

Tor-Einar Jarnbjo is right. The official description is:

> 1.2 km west of the village of Chukurayva, 5 kms south-east of the fortified town of Kechror, Gabeghiank District, Ayrarat Province, Armenia Maior (Kaghzvan District, Kars Region until 1920, at present Kars İli Kağızman İlçesi Kötek Bucağı), at an altitude of 1,949 meters above sea level (geographical coordinates: N 40° 14' 51.69'', E 42° 54' 49.07'').

Keçror is indeed an old Armenian name for the village Tunçkaya.